# C++ Write sorted contents of vector<string> to file

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

This currently reads a .txt file and sorts the contents. I'm trying to get it to write those sorted contents of the vector to a file. Currently it only writes one line, how can I can get it to put all lines in the new file? Thank you so much. -Kaiya

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch; cin>>ch;}

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("weblog.txt");
    vector<string> fileLines;

    //stack overflow example
    if (!myfile) //test the file
    {
        cout << "Unable to open the file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        fileLines.push_back(line);
        //cout << line << '\n';
    }

    sort(fileLines.begin(), fileLines.end()); //sorting string vector

    for (string &s : fileLines)
    {
        cout << s << " ";
        ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt");
        newfile << s << " ";
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt");
for (string &s : fileLines)
{
   cout << s << " ";
   newfile << s << " ";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating `newfile` for every loop iteration overwrites the content of the file, by default.

Either open `newfile` before the last loop, or open it in append mode within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are creating a new file in each iteration of your loop! 
    ofstream newfile("newfile.txt");
should be written before the loop.

```
ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt");
for (string &s : fileLines)
{
   cout << s << " ";
   newfile << s << " ";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt");

copy(fileLines.begin(), fileLines.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(newfile, " ") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete code that worked, thanks Xiaotian Pei for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch; cin>>ch;}

    int main()
    {
        string line;
        ifstream myfile("weblog.txt");
        vector<string> fileLines;

        if (!myfile) //test the file
        {
            cout << "Unable to open the file" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            fileLines.push_back(line);
        }

        sort(fileLines.begin(), fileLines.end()); //sorting string vector

        ofstream newfile ("newfile.txt"); //write to new file
        for (string &s : fileLines)
        {
            cout << s << " ";
            newfile << s << " ";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```